# How to avoid Spring WebFlux filter from being called twice?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-webflux

After a long exhaustive search, asking for help on this. I'm writing a `JwtTokenFilter` in **Spring WebFlux coupled with Spring Security.** The problem is this filter is being called twice on a single request. The filter code is below.

```
    @Component
class JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter(
    @Autowired val tokenProvider: JwtTokenProvider
) : WebFilter {
    private val HEADER_PREFIX = "Bearer "

    override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void?> {
        val token = resolveToken(exchange.request)
        return if (StringUtils.hasText(token) && tokenProvider.validateToken(token)) {
            val authentication: Authentication = tokenProvider.getAuthentication(token)
            chain.filter(exchange)
                .contextWrite(ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withAuthentication(authentication))
        } else
            chain.filter(exchange)
    }

    private fun resolveToken(request: ServerHttpRequest): String? {
        val bearerToken = request.headers.getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)
        return if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken!!.startsWith(HEADER_PREFIX)) {
            bearerToken.substring(7)
        } else null
    }
}
```

This problem can be avoided by removing **@Component** annotation on the filter but that would mean I'll have to create this object and all its dependencies in the path, which totally takes away the advantage of **dependency inversion** of Spring. Therefore, I want to retain using the Spring annotations to get the work done. However, this creates the problem that the filter is registered at two places i.e.., at servlet container and Spring Security.

***This solution presented in [this](https://ngdeveloper.com/resolved-spring-boot-jwt-filter-called-twice/) article talks about it.***

But couldn't find a way to apply the solution on that article to WebFilter as the solution in the article is for servlet Filters.

So, is there a way to avoid this bean from being invoked by servlet container and allow it to be invoked by Spring Security only. Or something else is the issue in the code that you see?

Comment: hmm, @Toerktumlare did not know about that. Do you know if it can be used when OAuth2 is not being used? I want to have a simple JWT authorization mechanism without OAuth2.

Comment: since i have no idea what you mean when you say "simple JWT authorization", what's "simple" is relative. My suggestion, is that you read the link i posted on how it works, and then you decide if it works for you or not.